# 'Access Denied' error while uploading a document to a Library

Tags: 2010, permissions, document-library, access-denied

I am unable to add documents to a Library.

When I try to upload a document it says 'Access Denied' instead of a "New Document" form. The group which is getting this error has "Design - Can view, add, update, delete, approve, and customize." permission.

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: is this any library or a specific library?

Comment: Specific Library only

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing your account from the group and granting those same permissions explicitly?  If the error persists, does it go away when you elevate to full privileges?

Other things you can try/verify:

1. Clear your browser cache and delete your cookies.
2. Ensure there are no web app rules that explicitly deny any rights.
3. Check to ensure the DB where the site collection resides has space.

Comment: Yes, Once I give Full rights to a group of users, everything works perfectly. Does this error has any relation to SP1 Upgrade?

Comment: I am not aware of permission related issues (outside of UPS) after SP1 is applied.  Can you replicate it on another library (i.e. design rights being denied access)?  If it can be isolated to this single library, you may want to consider creating a new one, validate it works with design rights and then migrate the content to the new library.

Comment: Will removing the users from the library & creating new permissions again solve the issue? As migrating the content will be difficult for me!